# Making a checkbox recognize its intended data

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, html-table

Level: PHP Learner

I'm stuck with a checkbox problem.  I have a db that contains names and unique id numbers.

Using a query, I am pulling a selection of students and showing them to a user in an ultra simple HTML table on a form.  Each row begins with a checkbox.  The method is POST.  So far, so good.  My table looks like this:

```
+-----------+----------+----------+
|   SELECT  |    NAME  |    ID    |
+-----------+----------+----------+
|   []      |    John  |    2233  |
+-----------+----------+----------+
|   []      |    Susie |    5577  |
+-----------+----------+----------+

[-SUBMIT-]
```

My problem is that I cannot seem to make the checkbox associate with each record's unique ID.  Once the user has selected rows and clicked submit, the `$_POST` array remains empty.

None of my beginners books reference this specific issue.  They go through the "regular" checkbox routines that don't involve interacting with rows from a db.  I also could not find an issue on Stackoverflow that addresses this.  Also tried Google:  plenty of stuff on checkboxes, but I couldn't find any that helped me on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit: If your form doesn't get more complex as you describe, take Doug Neiner's approach, as it is way simpler. This approach is right if a table is likely to have a  number of columns.

I like to do it this way:

Number the checkboxes sequentially (1 to 100) and add a hidden field connecting the row number to a real database ID:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="row_1" value="checked">`
<input type='hidden' name='row_1_id' value='2233'>`
```

Store the total number of rows in another hidden field

`<input type='hidden' name='row_total' value='99'>`

Then, in the receiving script, iterate from 1 to the total number of rows using `for`, check whether this row was selected, and get the associated database ID:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $number_of_rows; $i++)
{
  if ($_POST["row_$i"] == "checked")
   {
     $database_id_unsafe = $_POST["row_{$i}_id"];
 ...
```

the latter, of course, needs to be properly sanitized and escaped in case it is processed further.

Comment: +1 Nice, you could skip the test by using this `<input type="checkbox" name="row[2223]" value="checked" /><input type="hidden" name="row[2223]" value="not_checked" />` then the value would be submitted regardless of if the checkbox was submitted. Then you just have to iterate over the returned `row` parameter using a `$key => $value` pair and you would have both the ID and the checked/unchecked state. Or am I thinking Ruby again :)

Comment: Interesting idea. I can't test it right now but sounds like it would work!

Comment: Thanks, Pekka.  Yes, the actual number of fields will potentially grow substantially.  I'm going to try to implement this concept.

Answer (score 7):

Just do something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="2233" /> ... rest of row
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="5577" /> ... rest of row
```

Now, in PHP, you can get the selected `ids` like this:

```
$ids = $_POST['ids'];
if( empty($ids) ) $ids = array();
```

This sets `$ids` to an empty array if the form was submitted without any of the checkboxes checked.

Comment: `[]` needs to become `Array()` (or this is a PHP notation I don't know). And PHP, unlike Javascript has `or` :D

Comment: Haha, yes, that was a special language I like to call "PHPRubyScript" :) Thanks for catching those errors.

Comment: Lol.. my answer has glaring problems, and I get no downvotes. I fix them, and it is downvoted without comment.

Comment: Thank you, Doug.  I'm afraid that the PHP portion of your suggestion is a bit over my head, but I will work with it until I understand it.

Comment: Hey, no problem. It just gives you a PHP array with the id's. For instance if both were checked, it would give you the equivalent of `$ids = array(2233, 5577)`